# how would I go about mimicking express / connects next() feature?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I was given a task to recreate Express' middleware architecture and I think I'm getting lost in callback land at the moment. I'm able to respond to the requests and everything, but what I'm having trouble with is implementing the next() functionality the Express provides. Here is the relevant code I've got so far:

using my middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.write("Humpty "); 
});
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.write("Dumpty "); 
});
app.use("/sat", function(req, res, next){
    res.end("sat on a wall \n");
});
```

then in the actual middleware file I have:

```
module.exports = {
    use: function(url, cb){    // how do i add a next() arg to cb?
        if(cb === undefined){    // if 1 arg passed, must be function
            cb = url;   
        }
        server.on("request", cb);
    }
}
```

basically what I thinkk I need is access to **cb**'s arguments, which are the request and the response to filter out the request url and write the appropriate message, but I can't access them. Logging cb.length works, but thats just getting the length of the arguments passed to it, I can't access the actual values of the arguments. Also, Node's **server.on** event only has two arguments, **request** and **response**, so I'm a bit confused as to how Connect / Express introduce the 3rd argument **next**. Am I doing this the right way? or way off track?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can append arguments to a function is to invoke it explicitly inside an anonymous function.

```
// cb and next must be defined in this scope.
// then...

server.on("request", function (req, res) {
    cb(req, res, next);
});
```

You can also look at [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for some other possible options.

Comment: ahh let me try this that looks good. I think I was overthinking it X0. I'll update when I get a chance to try it (at work right now), thanks!

Comment: ok so this definitely put me on the right track, thanks @Trott, unfortunately I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around this task, as I keep getting closer in one area, it seems I go back in another :| . heres a link to the problem I'm working on: https://gist.github.com/cilix-sm/10e83ab37b1e2a953d4c . Any chance you could take a look and possibly give me another push in the right direction? I'm still trying, but my brains about fried.